# Mutate all columns to numeric with specific column headers using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that has a bunch of columns.  Some of the columns end with a _id.  For example, food_id, drink_id.  I want to convert the data in all columns that end with "_id" from Factors to numeric.  How would I go about doing that in dplyr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df1 %<>%
   mutate_at(vars(ends_with("_id")), funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

If we want to select specific 'id' columns

```
df2 %<>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches("^(food|drink).*_id")), funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

Or the reverse logic

```
df2 %<>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("_id"), -matches("^(snack|dessert).*_id")),
                funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

Or create an index of columns before with `grep` and then use that in `mutate_at`

```
i1 <- !grepl("^(snack|dessert).*_id$", names(df2)) & grepl("_id$", names(df2))
df2 %<>%
     mutate_at(vars(which(i1)), funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(food_id = factor(1:5), drink_id = factor(6:10), value = rnorm(5))


df2 <- data.frame(food_id = factor(1:5), drink_id = factor(6:10), value = LETTERS[1:5],
snack_id = factor(1:5),  dessert_id = factor(11:15))
```

Comment: Thank you!  What is the (as.character(.) in there for?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz  If you are converting `factor` class to numeric directly, then it will change the values to the integer storage mode instead of the actual values.  For e.g. `v1 <- factor(6:10); as.numeric(v1)#
[1] 1 2 3 4 5` and `as.numeric(as.character(v1))#[1]  6  7  8  9 10`

Comment: One additional question: How would I exclude a few specific columns on the mutate at?  I want to mutate all columns that end with "_id" with the exception of 3 or 4 columns.  Those needs to remain character columns.

Comment: @Jazzmatazz  If there is any pattern you can use those pattern in `matches`

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example?  Say I use the code above to account for drink_id,  food_id and the remainder of the _id columns but want to exclude snack_id and dessert_id?

Comment: Thanks akrun!  I wasn't that clear on my question.  How would I write the code that converts all columns with _id to numeric with the exception of snack_id, and dessert_id?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz  Updated the post.  Hope it helps